# paypal permission sdk and express checkout

Tags: php, paypal

Using paypal permission sdk, I got token and tokenSecret after granting the permission. Then using the Oauth, I have received the signature key. Now I want to call the Express Checkout call with this signature? How its possible?

This is the step I did in the permission API,

1. Get the Classic Api credentials from Sandbox with Application ID
2. Using the Permission API.. Finally i got Access token and token Secret.
3. Then using paypal OAuth.. received the signature.

Now I am stuck with next step. Even I didn't get the call "GetBasicPersonalData"

Comment: Did you try passing it in the SUBJECT parameter of your Express Checkout API requests?  So you would use your own USER, PASS, and SIGNATURE, but then you'd also add the SUBJECT with the value of the token you got from permissions.  I'm not 100% sure that'll work, but I'd give it a shot.

Comment: I have added "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SUBJECT" as email address (merchant , as behalf).  Still Error

Comment: Did you try passing the token there instead of their email?

Comment: I have passed email address. Getting the response as Authentication Failed

Comment: I keep asking you to try the token, you keep saying you're trying the email address.  What about the token???

Comment: I have also tried responseToken. Still same status

Comment: Also.. Could you please check this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350137/paypal-permission-api-getbasicpersonaldata-in-php